Is there anything wrong with doing a buck then boost converter instead of a buck boost
I was trying to find a buck-boost converter that can do 5A with a voltage input range of 12 and a output range of 5-20 for usb pd. I found that if I did a buck then boost converter the price for both IC were less then half the cost then a buck-boost controller. Is there anything wrong with doing 2 separate controllers?



Is there anything wrong with doing 2 separate controllers?


Twice as many inductors (two) are needed and this may make up for more than the price difference you calculated.
Two lots of supply decoupling capacitors are needed.
More PCB space is needed
Overall, performance may not be as good as a single buck-boost device
The power efficiency of your specific circuit might be around 82% whereas a combined circuit might be as high as 90%
Your circuit uses cheaper (less efficient) non-synchronous conversion chips

